# Typescript custom type guards and array operations

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types, typescript-typings

Sorry if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find the answer I am looking for.

I am starting to experiment with TypeScript and I came across [used-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards). I wanted to use them to check if an array is empty but I can't figure out how to do it properly.
This is what I tried so far.

```
function isEmpty<T>(array: Array<T>): array is [] {
  return array.length === 0;
}  

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const result: string[] = [];

while (!isEmpty(arr)) {
  result.push(arr.pop())
  //          ^^^^^^^^^ Type error here because pop() returns string or undefined if the array is empty 
}
```

It seems that TypeScript is unable to narrow down the return type of Array.prototype.pop() as it doesn't have access to its implementation and just relies on the function's signature.

Is there a way to make this work? I am most interested in readability and type safety.
Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you really need that? Why not just set boolean as return type?

Comment: Does TS complains with simple `while (arr.length) {` ?

Comment: If I were to have boolean as return type of `isEmpty`, I should just check for `while (arr.length)`. I am trying to have the type checker know by itself that I am not pushing `undefined` into `result`.
And even with `while (arr.length)`, the type error is the same

Comment: Then `while (arr.length) { if(arr.length) { result.push(arr.pop()) } }` - That is redondant... But should satisfy TS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use type assertion to tell the compiler what will the type of items `arr.pop()` return be because `arr` could be empty and the type of result variable is an array of strings.
So the code will look like this:

```
const isEmpty = <T>(array: T[]): array is [] => {
  return array.length === 0;
};

const arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
const result: string[] = [];

while (!isEmpty(arr)) {
  result.push(arr.pop() as string);
}
```